# How to update Formstate.isValid to true when unregistering required inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I'm building a front-end shopping cart checkout page using React Hook Form. I am trying to get so that when I click on the "cash delivery" radio button, it will unregister and hide the input fields in the "cash-money" div. That way, when I hit the "continue and pay" button, it will render the PayModal and validate the form without the "ePin" and "eMoney" register inputs. But it's not pulling up the modal even if all the fields are entered correctly.

I was able to get it to work if I click on the "e-money" radio button and then click back to the "cash" radio but not by the first click. I was also able to get it to work if I console log the Formstate.IsValid property, but not when it's not console logged. How can I get the IsValid property to be true immediately after unregistering required inputs?

````
const CheckoutPage = () => {
  const [method,
    setMethod] = useState("e-money");
  const [payModal,
    setPayModal] = useState(false);

  const {subTotal, vatCost, cartItems} = useSelector(store => store.cart);
  const {register, unregister, handleSubmit, formState, formState: {
      errors
    }} = useForm({mode: "onChange"});

  const shippingCost = 50;
  const totalCost = subTotal + shippingCost + vatCost;

  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  const onChangeValue = (method) => {
    setMethod(method);

  }

  const toggleHandler = () => {
    if(formState.isValid){
      setPayModal(prev => !prev);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (method === "cash") {
      unregister("ePIN");
      unregister("eNumber");
    }

  },[method, unregister])

  return (
    <div className="checkout-container">
      {payModal && (
        <div className="modal-overlay">
          <CheckoutModal/>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="checkout-content">
        <div className="checkout-navbar">
          <Navbar/>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
        <Link to={"/"}>
          <Button className="back-btn" text={"Go Back"} type={"type-5"}/>
        </Link>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="checkout-form">

            <div className="checkout-div">
              <h1 className="checkout-title">CHECKOUT</h1>
              <div className="billing-details">
                <h5>BILLING DETAILS</h5>
                <div className="billing-details-content">
                  <div className="billing-form-group">
                    <div
                      className={`${errors.name
                      ? "error-class"
                      : ""} label-div`}>
                      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                      {errors.name && <span>Field Required</span>}
                    </div>
                    <input
                      className={`${errors.name
                      ? "input-error"
                      : ""}`}
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      placeholder="Alexei Ward"
                      {...register("name", {required: true, maxLength: 100})}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="billing-form-group">
                    <div
                      className={`${errors.email
                      ? "error-class"
                      : ""} label-div`}>
                      <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
                      {errors.email && <span>Field Required</span>}
                    </div>
                    <input
                      className={`${errors.email
                      ? "input-error"
                      : ""}`}
                      type="email"
                      name="email"
                      placeholder="alexei@mail.com"
                      {...register("email", {required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="billing-form-group">
                    <div
                      className={`${errors.phoneNumber
                      ? "error-class"
                      : ""} label-div`}>
                      <label htmlFor="telephone">Phone Number</label>
                      {errors.phoneNumber && <span>Field Required</span>}
                    </div>
                    <input
                      className={`${errors.phoneNumber
                      ? "input-error"
                      : ""}`}
                      type="tel"
                      name="telephone"
                      placeholder="202-555-0136"
                      {...register("phoneNumber", {required: true, min: 10, maxLength: 12})}/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="shipping-info">
                <h5>SHIPPING INFO</h5>
                <div className="shipping-content">
                  <div className="shipping-form-group">
                    <div
                      className={`${errors.address
                      ? "error-class"
                      : ""} label-div`}>
                      <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
                      {errors.address && <span>Field Required</span>}
                    </div>

                    <input
                      className={`${errors.address
                      ? "input-error"
                      : ""}`}
                      type="text"
                      name="address"
                      placeholder="1137 Williams Avenue"
                      {...register("address", {required: true})}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="shipping-flex-div">
                    <div className="shipping-form-group">
                      <div
                        className={`${errors.zipCode
                        ? "error-class"
                        : ""} label-div`}>
                        <label htmlFor="zip-code">Zip Code</label>
                        {errors.zipCode && <span>Field Required</span>}
                      </div>

                      <input
                        className={`${errors.zipCode
                        ? "input-error"
                        : ""}`}
                        type="number"
                        name="zip-code"
                        placeholder="10001"
                        {...register("zipCode", {required: true, min: 5, maxLength: 5})}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="shipping-form-group">
                      <div
                        className={`${errors.city
                        ? "error-class"
                        : ""} label-div`}>
                        <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                        {errors.city && <span>Field Required</span>}
                      </div>

                      <input
                        className={`${errors.city
                        ? "input-error"
                        : ""}`}
                        type="text"
                        name="city"
                        placeholder="New York"
                        {...register("city", {required: true})}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="shipping-form-group">
                      <div
                        className={`${errors.country
                        ? "error-class"
                        : ""} label-div`}>
                        <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
                        {errors.country && <span>Field Required</span>}
                      </div>

                      <input
                        className={`${errors.country
                        ? "input-error"
                        : ""}`}
                        type="text"
                        name="country"
                        placeholder="United States"
                        {...register("country", {required: true})}/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="payment-details">
                <h5>PAYMENT DETAILS</h5>
                <div className="payment-content">
                  <div className="payment-method-div">
                    <div className="payment-form-group">
                      <label>Payment Method</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="payment-form-group">
                      <div
                        className={`payment-method ${method === "e-money"
                        ? "payment-highlight"
                        : ""}`}
                        onClick={() => onChangeValue("e-money")}>
                        <label className="payment-label">
                          e-Money
                        </label>
                        <input
                          className="payment-radio"
                          onClick={() => onChangeValue("e-money")}
                          type="radio"
                          readOnly
                          checked={method === "e-money"}/>
                      </div>
                      <div
                        className={`payment-method ${method === "cash"
                        ? "payment-highlight"
                        : ""}`}
                        onClick={() => onChangeValue("cash")}>
                        <label className="payment-label">
                          Cash On Delivery
                        </label>
                        <input
                          className="payment-radio"
                          onClick={() => {
                          onChangeValue("cash")
                        }}
                          type="radio"
                          readOnly
                          checked={method === "cash"}/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="cash-money-div">
                      {method === "e-money"
                        ? (
                          <div className="e-money-div">
                            <div className="payment-form-group">
                              <div
                                className={`${errors.eNumber
                                ? "error-class"
                                : ""} label-div`}>
                                <label htmlFor="e-money-number">e-Money Number</label>
                                {errors.eNumber && <span>Field Required</span>}

                              </div>

                              <input
                                className={`${errors.eNumber
                                ? "input-error"
                                : ""}`}
                                type="number"
                                name="e-money-number"
                                placeholder="238521993"
                                {...register("eNumber", {required: true, min: 9, maxLength: 9})}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="payment-form-group">
                              <div
                                className={`${errors.ePIN
                                ? "error-class"
                                : ""} label-div`}>
                                <label htmlFor="e-money-pin">e-Money PIN</label>
                                {errors.ePIN && <span>Field Required</span>}
                              </div>

                              <input
                                className={`${errors.ePIN
                                ? "input-error"
                                : ""}`}
                                type="number"
                                name="e-money-pin"
                                placeholder="6891"
                                {...register("ePIN", {required: true, min: 4, maxLength: 4})}/>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        )
                        : (

                          <div className="cash-div">
                            <img src="../../assets/checkout/icon-cash-on-delivery.svg" alt="cash"/>
                            <p>The "Cash on Delivery" option enables you to pay in cash when our delivery
                              courier arrives at your residence. Just make sure your address is correct so
                              that your order will not be cancelled.</p>
                          </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="summary-div">
              <div className="summary-content">
                <h3 className="summary-title">SUMMARY</h3>
                <ul className="summary-cart">
                  {cartItems.map(item => {
                    return <li key={item.id}>
                      <div className="summary-cart-info">
                        <img className="summary-cart-img" src={`../.${item.img}`} alt="thumbnail"/>
                        <div className="summary-cart-desc">
                          <p className="name">{item.name}</p>
                          <p className="price">$ {item.price}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <p className="summary-item-count">x{item.count}</p>
                    </li>
                  })
}

                </ul>
                <div className="totals-div">
                  <div className="subtotal-price">
                    <h4>SUBTOTAL</h4>
                    <p>{`$ ${subTotal.toLocaleString("en-US")}`}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="shipping-price">
                    <h4>SHIPPING</h4>
                    <p>$ 50</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="vat-price">
                    <h4>VAT (INCLUDED)</h4>
                    <p>{`$ ${vatCost.toLocaleString("en-US")}`}</p>
                  </div>
                  <br/>
                  <div className="grand-total-price">
                    <h4>TOTAL</h4>
                    <p className="grand-total-color">$ {totalCost.toLocaleString("en-US")}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <Button
                  onClick={toggleHandler}
                  className="pay-btn"
                  text={"CONTINUE & PAY"}
                  type={"type-1"}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
} ```
````

Comment: In toggler handler set to pay to true don't use !prev use this " setPayModal(true) or setPayModal(()=>true);